# Is there a standard-compliant way to determine the alignment of a non-static member?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-traits

Suppose I have some structure `S` and a non-static member `member`, as in this example:

```
struct S { alignas(alignof(void *)) char member[sizeof(void *)]; };
```

How do you get the alignment of `member`?

The operator `alignof` can only be applied to complete types, not expressions [[in 7.6.2.5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.alignof#1)], although GCC allows it, so `alignof(S::member)` and Clang supports it.

What is the "language-lawyerly" standard way to do it without this restriction?

Also, `sizeof` allows expression arguments, is there a reason for the asymmetry?

The practical concern is to be able to get the alignment of members of template structures, you can do `decltype` to get their type, `sizeof` to get their size, but then you also need the alignment.

Comment: What are you looking for? Are you expecting `alignof(S::member)` to be `alignof(void *)` or to be `alignof(S)` or something else? It's not clear to me what "alignment of a non-static member" means.

Comment: maybe `offsetof(S, member);` is what you want? Can check it for being a multiple of `4` or `alignof(void *)` or whatever, if you like.

Comment: I don't think you can... Just introduce a constexpr value that's the alignment you want and use that instead of alignof wherever you need it (including in alignas) (also the `alignof` in `alignas(alignof(void*))` is redundant)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but please observe the question refers to the language standard and not practical workarounds

Comment: @Justin unfortunately the  C++ standards people use a jargon that is not easily decipherable, they refer to what we could call "instance members" (as opposed to "class members") as "non-static members"

Comment: @TheCppZoo Thanks. I understand what "non-static member" means. My point is that "alignment of data-member" is unclear. The "alignment" of a type or variable refers to what memory addresses said variable can be placed at: the address must be a multiple of the alignment. With that idea, the alignment of a data-member would be something which describes the possible addresses the member could be at, which is `alignof(S)` but not a clean multiple, rather `K * alignof(S) + offsetof(S, member)` for some `K`. Or you could just be asking for the alignment of the member if it was a variable on its own.

Comment: @Justin I mean the symmetrical operation to setting the alignment with `alignas`.  One can use `alignas` on a *member*, then we should be allowed to ask for the alignment

Answer (score 0):

The alignment of a type or variable is a description of what memory addresses the variable can inhabit—the address must be a multiple of the alignment<sup>*</sup>. However, for data-members, the address of the data-member can be any `K * alignof(S) + offsetof(S, member)`. Let's define the alignment of a data-member to be the maximum possible integer `E` such that `&some_s.member` is always a multiple of `E`.

Given a type `S` with member `member`, let `A = alignof(S), O = offsetof(S, member)`.
The valid addresses of `S{}.member` are `V = K * A + O` for some integer `K`.
`V = K * A + O = gcd(A, O) * (K * A / gcd(A, O) + O / gcd(A, O))`.
For the case where `K = 1`, no other factors exist.
Thus, `gcd(A, O)` is the best factor valid for unknown `K`.

In other words, `"alignof(S.member)" == gcd(alignof(S), offsetof(S, member))`.

Note that this alignment is always a power of two, as `alignof(S)` is always a power of two.

<sup>*: In my brief foray into the standard, I couldn't find this guarantee, meaning that the address of the variable *could* be `K * alignment + some_integer`. However, this doesn't affect the final result.</sup>

---

We can define a macro to compute the alignment of a data-member:

```
#include <cstddef> // for offsetof(...)
#include <numeric> // for std::gcd

// Must be a macro, as `offsetof` is a macro because the member name must be known
// at preprocessing time.
#define ALIGNOF_MEMBER(cls, member) (::std::gcd(alignof(cls), offsetof(cls, member)))
```

This is only guaranteed valid for standard layout types, as [`offsetof` is only guaranteed valid for standard layout types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). If the class is not standard layout, this operation is conditionally supported.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <numeric>

struct S1 { char foo; alignas(alignof(void *)) char member[sizeof(void *)]; };
struct S2 { char foo; char member[sizeof(void *)]; };

#define ALIGNOF_MEMBER(cls, member) (::std::gcd(alignof(cls), offsetof(cls, member)))

int f1() { return ALIGNOF_MEMBER(S1, member); } // returns alignof(void *) == 8
int f2() { return ALIGNOF_MEMBER(S1, foo); }    // returns 8*
int f3() { return ALIGNOF_MEMBER(S2, member); } // returns 1

// *: alignof(S1) == 8, so the `foo` member must always be at an alignment of 8
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/i9JJ1i)

Comment: I do not agree with the treatment you are giving, first, the question of the alignment of a member has no ambiguity, since the alignment of the containing aggregate must be knowable, furthermore, one can specify the exact alignment desired using `alignas` for a *member*, what I think is potentially a mistake in the standard is that there is no way to "retrieve" the alignment information, even if the source code specifies its minimum.

Comment: @TheCppZoo I see what you mean now. You mean, "alignment as in any `alignas(...)` specified for the member, or just `alignof(member-type)` if no `alignas(...)`." You either have to use the GNU extension as you realized, or you can specify the alignment as e.g. a `static constexpr auto member_align = alignof(void *); alignas(member_align) char member[sizeof(void *)];` so that you can extract the alignment.

Comment: @Justin *"for data-members, the address of the data-member can be any `K * alignof(S) + offsetof(S, member)`..."* **You should explicitly write what `K` and `S` stands for in your equation as not everyone(like those who see this for the first time) understands them.** Other reason for adding what they mean is that it will make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. In the general case, declaring a non-static data member with an alignment specifier might not change the layout of the class that contains it. In the below example, if (as is most common) `int` has a size and alignment of 4, the structs `S1` and `S2` are likely to have the same layout, with a total size of 8 bytes. Each is likely to have 3 bytes of padding at the end:

```
struct S1 {
    int x;
    char y;
};

struct S2 {
    int x;
    alignas(4) char y;
};
```

This prevents us from using any information about the layout of the struct to determine the alignment of `y`. And as the OP noted, `alignof(S::member)` isn't valid.

By the way, there also isn't any way to query the alignment specifier of a regular variable. You can use the `std::align` function to check whether the variable is allocated at an address that is appropriately aligned for an object with alignment X, but this doesn't imply that the variable was actually declared with an alignment of X or greater. It could have been declared with an alignment less than X and coincidentally ended up allocated at an address that could have supported an object with alignment X.

Since this functionality is unsupported not only for non-static data members but also regular variables, I'm inclined to think that it's not an oversight; it's deliberately not supported because it's not useful. *The compiler* needs to know the alignment specifier so that it can allocate the variable or data member appropriately. That is not *the programmer's* job. Sure, the programmer may need to know the alignment requirement of *a type* in order to appropriately allocate memory for instances of that type, but you cannot, as the programmer, create additional instances of a variable, other than by triggering some condition that makes it happen automatically (*e.g.*, continuing to the next iteration of a loop will deallocate and reallocate automatic variables in the loop's body). Nor can you, *as of now*, create a second class at compile time that's guaranteed to be layout-compatible with a given class, which is the main application I can think of for the hypothetical "query alignment of non-static data member" feature. I expect that, once C++ provides enough other reflection functionality so that something like that is close to possible, someone will also put forth a realistic proposal to add a way to query the alignment of a non-static data member.